# Windows 10: Error accessing certain settings

Tags: operating-systems, windows-10, display-settings

I've just completed a clean install of Windows 10 Pro on my Thinkpad W520 (4270cto) and I've noticed a strange error that occurs when attempting to adjust certain system settings. For example, if I access "Display settings" then "Advanced display settings" and attempt to click "ClearType text," "Color calibration," or "Display adapter properties" I get the following Windows error message as displayed in the attached image:

[image: Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.]

"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

The strange thing is that I can access any of these settings either by finding the `.exe` file directly, or via the Control Panel. I am an administrator on this machine and the only one who uses it-- is this actually a security/policy issue? When I first saw the issue, I even re-installed the OS thinking a file might have been missing or corrupted, and the same issue occurs. I've noticed the issue also occurs with settings involving `rundll32.exe`.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: it would be interesting to see if you have the same issues when creating a simple users account and adjusting the same things.

Comment: I just wanted to post an update that somehow the issue seems to have entirely resolved itself, and I have no idea how. As far as I know, there was no update installed, or changes applied to any security settings-- I am baffled. I wish I had more to offer here, but I suppose if someone else experiences this issue, s/he can contribute here with potential findings.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by disabling auto login for my user.

To do that press <kbd>Windows key + R</kbd> and write `netplwiz`. This will open a manager software for users. Check the box where it says `Users must enter a username and password`. Apply and restart Windows.

Comment: could u elaborate how u did it,it will help future users whom struggle with it